# django: proper way to send POST to view from potentially unlimited forms

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms, django-forms

In my django application I have a page where the user can theoretically add as many addresses as they want. I have a django address form that contains typical information (address, city, postal code) and the user can create as many of these django forms as they want, and the forms are all identical other than a unique id. My problem is that I need the user to be able to click a submit button which will submit all the forms to a view where I can process the addresses.

Other answers to similar questions don't seem to work for me, currently my approach involves looping through the forms and calling jquery's submit() function on each one when the submit button is pressed, but that approach isn't working. Ideally I would end up with a POST request in my view with all of the address information from all of the forms so I can easily process it within the view.

Comment: Have you looked into formsets? As far as I can see they do exactly what you need. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using ModelForms with prefixes in the following way:

models.py:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['street', 'city']
```

views.py:

```
def addresses(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in range(int(request.POST['num_of_addresses'])):
            address = AddressForm(request.POST, prefix='address%d'%i)
            address.save()
        return HttpResponse('Addresses saved successfully')

    num_of_addresses = 10 # As many as you want
    forms = []

    for i in range(num_of_addresses):
        forms.append(AddressForm(prefix='address%d'%i))

    return render(request, 'address.html', context={
        'forms': forms,
        'num_of_addresses': num_of_addresses,
    })
```

address.html:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for form in forms %}
    {{ form }}
    <br />
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="hidden" name="num_of_addresses" value="{{ num_of_addresses }}" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you inspect the generated HTML, you'll see each element in the address forms will have a prefix in the form `addressN-` which helps the view tell one from another and save them accordingly.

You could also have a jquery function that adds an address form dynamically (remembering to increment the num_of_addresses field as well), and it would work perfectly.

Hope this helps